# How do I find all the monospace fonts in Font Book?

Tags: mac, fonts

I would like to create a new collection of fonts in Font Book for all my monospace fonts (so that I can choose them later in other apps more easily) but I can't figure out an easy way to do this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Comment: That doesn't necessarily contain all the monospace fonts. It's just a predefined collection added by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, how many do you have? It shouldn't be too hard to just select them manually.

- Default monospace: Monaco, Menlo, Courier, Courier New, Andale Mono
- Default not monospace: American Typewriter
- Other common monospace: DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Lucida Console, Consolas, Droid Sans Mono

Comment: I have a lot, and I am getting more. Besides the ones you listed I also have Inconsolata, Droid Sans Japanese, Droid Sans Slashed, and probably more. I like fonts ^^

Comment: Yeah, I've also made my own monospace font based on Monofur... I've split my /Library/Fonts/ into subfolders, but I stopped keeping collections because it's so annoying to update them manually.